# Interpolating a density plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, interpolation

I am solving a complicated series of equations (involving FindRoot and PolyLog), and finally I get this plot
[image]

Code here:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
q := 1.6*10^-19; (* Electron charge in Coulomb *)
me := 9.1*10^-31; (* Free electron rest mass in kg *)
h := 6.63*10^-34;  (* Reduced Planck's constant in J.s *)
kb := 1.38*10^-23; (* Boltzmann constant in J/K *)
FD[d_, η_] := -PolyLog[
    d + 1, -E^η];(* Defining the Fermi-Dirac integrals *)
Nc[d_, gs_, gv_, meff_, T_] := 
  gs*gv*((2*π*meff*me*kb*T)/h^2)^(d/
   2);  (* Effective band-edge DOS in d dimensions *)
n[d_, gs_, gv_, meff_, T_, ηF_] := 
  Nc[d, gs, gv, meff, T]*
   FD[(d - 2)/
    2, ηF]*(100)^-d; (* Effective SI carrier density in d \
dimensions in cm units*)
ηS[d_, gs_, gv_, meff_, T_, v_, nd_] := 
 Quiet[Chop[
     FindRoot[
      1/2*(n[d, gs, gv, meff, T, η] + 
          n[d, gs, gv, meff, T, η - (q*v)/(kb*T)]) == 
       nd, {η, 1}]][[1]][[
   2]]]; (* Source Fermi Level at voltage v in d dimensions*)
Lkcore[d_, gs_, gv_, meff_, T_, v_, 
  nd_] := ((FD[d/2, ηS[d, gs, gv, meff, T, v, nd]] + 
     FD[d/2, ηS[d, gs, gv, meff, T, v, nd] - (q*v)/(kb*T)] - 
     2*FD[d/2, ηS[d, gs, gv, meff, T, 0, nd]])/(FD[(d - 1)/
      2, ηS[d, gs, gv, meff, T, v, nd]] - 
     FD[(d - 1)/
      2, ηS[d, gs, gv, meff, T, v, nd] - (q*v)/(kb*T)])^2); 
(* Quantum Inductance Kernel *)
Lk0[d_, gs_, gv_, meff_, T_] := (π*meff*me*d)/(
  q^2*Nc[d, gs, gv, meff, T]);
Lkall[d_, gs_, gv_, meff_, T_, v_, nd_] := 
  Lk0[d, gs, gv, meff, T]*Lkcore[d, gs, gv, meff, T, v, nd];
DensityPlot[{Lkall[1, 2, 1, 1, temp, 0.1, n1d]*10^3}, {temp, 0.01, 
  300}, {n1d, 10^3, 10^7}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Log"}]
```

As you can see that between 1 and 10 on x-axis we see some data that is missing which I believe is because of numerical error in the computation. I don't want to change anything in the calculation, is there any way to directly modify the plot as it is using interpolation or anything?

Comment: Please share the data and the code you use for generating the plot

Comment: @Fraccalo added the code

Comment: Directly modifying the plot would be very hard as it isn't a rectangular table with some values corrupt, but an unstructured collection of colored polygons, some of them missing. It's somewhat easier to extract the vertices along with their RGB colors and recreate the plot anew. `vertices = plot[[1, 1, 1, 1]]; colors = plot[[1, 1, 1, 3, 2]]` or something like that, you can look at the plot's internal structure via InputForm[plot]. But is this really worth it?